# What is chromium helper for flutter and android studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter

There are multiple Chromium Helper processes in my system. They eat up lots of resource and slow my MacBook significantly. So far I only know they are related to android studio and flutter application development.

I don't know what I've done so these process start to emerge. Can anyone tell me what do they do and how to turn them off?